# Can I use the google form form apps script to set "response receipts" to "always"?

Tags: google-apps-script

I am creating an apps-script to programmatically build Forms based on questions in a google sheet.

I am collecting email addresses (using `form.setCollectEmail(true);`).
Is there a similar form method or another way to set `response receipts` to "Always", as you can do through the regular form editor by clicking on Settings:

[image: Google Form settings block]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Google Apps Script currently does not provide a method to "set response receipts to always". But there is an open [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/78605510) on the issue tracker for you star so the developers will see how many developers are affected by the issue.